# How to set fixed number of elements of array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

How to set fixed number of elements of an array in Ruby.

eg. `a=["a","b","c","d"]`
Setting array size to 3 would output

```
a=["a","b","cd"]
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you saying that, in your example, the 3rd and 4th element are concatenated?

Comment: Yes they are concatenated, since I am reducing the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Array
  def squeeze(n, &p)
    p = Proc.new {|xs| xs.join} unless p
    arr = self[0..n-2]
    arr << p.call(self[n-1..-1])
  end
end

a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
a.squeeze(3) # => ["a", "b", "cde"]
```

It needs bounds checking but you get the idea.  Note that the "combining" function can be given as a block argument:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].squeeze(3) {|xs| xs.inject {|acc,x| acc+x}} # => [1, 2, 7]
```

Comment: Thats very good, Is there no native implementation within Ruby Array class that does this, I saw something like this before but can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 6):

If you knew the elements were just one-character strings, you could do something like:

```
a.join.split '', 3
```

Otherwise:

```
a[0..1] + [a[2..-1].join]
```

Or perhaps:

```
a[0..1] << a[2..-1].join
```